# AM chart not showing the date axis correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, amcharts

I am totally new to AM chart, trying to build bar chart and line chart with provided datasource with category axis as date and set parseDates= true. While rendering chart, months appears to be shifting. For the given data, when drilled down to months, say April bar is sitting on May grid line (as in fig), how do I shift it back in the right order, when in yearly view Dec sits on next year grid line ( Dec 2004 sits on on year 2005). Is there anyway to fix it?

I have my category axis as follow

```
            "categoryAxis": {
                "minPeriod": "hh",
                "parseDates": true,
                "labelRotation": 45,
               "labelOffset": 0,
              "centerLabelOnFullPeriod": false,
               "dateFormats": [ 
                               {period:'hh',format:'JJ:NN'},
                                {period:'DD',format:'MMM DD'},
                               {period:'WW',format:'MMM DD'},
                               {period:'MM',format:'MMM YYYY'},
                               { period: 'YYYY', format: 'YYYY' }],
```

Any help on this greatly appreciated,

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jogejyothish/yqrhmje4/) is provided

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Having looked at your data I can see that when you are adding into your graph you are placing a value on the last day of the month.  If you could put the value as the first of every month instead then you will get the data to show as you are wanting.

For example, instead of using...

```
{ "DateField": "2009-05-31T00:00:00", "Value1": 126.00, "Value2": -46.00, "Value3": 80.00, "Value4": 172.00 }
{ "DateField": "2009-06-30T00:00:00", "Value1": 132.00, "Value2": -49.00, "Value3": 83.00, "Value4": 181.00 }
```

use this instead...

```
{ "DateField": "2009-05-01T00:00:00", "Value1": 126.00, "Value2": -46.00, "Value3": 80.00, "Value4": 172.00 }
{ "DateField": "2009-06-01T00:00:00", "Value1": 132.00, "Value2": -49.00, "Value3": 83.00, "Value4": 181.00 }
```

I have also spotted that you have an error in your graph components.  You have spelt **lineThickness** as **liValue3hickness**

```
            {
                "balloonText": "[[title]]: [[value]]% ([[category]])",
                "liValue3hickness": 3,     /*SHOULD BE "lineThickness" : 3,*/
                "title": "Value3",
                "valueField": "Value3",
                "lineColor": "#FFC000"
            }
```

Comment: Thanks Simon for the response, I cant actually change the data, thnaks for pointing out the typo liValue3hickness,

Answer (score 0):

I changed the column width to  "columnWidth": 0.5, set   "minPeriod": "MM", and                     "dateFormats": [

```
                                {period:'MM',format:'MMM YYYY'},
                                { period: 'YYYY', format: 'YYYY' }],
```

It worked for me, Thanks for helping me Simon, you gave me the insight,

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `equalSpacing` property

```
categoryAxis: {
  parseDates: true,
  equalSpacing: true,
}
```

To manually adjust the size, use `columnWidth`

```
graphs: [{
  type: 'column',
  columnWidth: .5 // Half of a full column
}]
```